# kafka-node on ready event is not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka

I have created singleton  class for Kafka client and producer to create only one object.
I need to publish the same topics multiple times without creating new Client and producer instance.
I found producer.on('ready',fn(){}) is not getting triggered using same client and producer instance ,only first time it gets triggered when i am having new client and producer object.

Here the sample code:

Singleton class:

```
const kafka = require('kafka-node');
const logger = require('./../../../../applogger');
const kafkaConfig = require('./../../../../config/config');

function ConnectionProvider() {
    let kafkaConnection = undefined;
    let client = undefined;

    this.getConnection = () => {

        if (!this.kafkaConnection) {
            logger.info("Creating new kafka connection ------------------------------------- ");
            this.client = new kafka.Client(kafkaConfig.ZOOKPER_HOST);
            this.kafkaConnection = new kafka.Producer(this.client);
        }
        return this.kafkaConnection;
    };
    this.getClient = () => {
        if (!this.client) {
            logger.info("Creating new kafka Client ------------------------------------- ");
            this.client = new kafka.Client(kafkaConfig.ZOOKPER_HOST);
        }
        return this.client;

    }
    process.on('SIGINT', function() {
        logger.info("Going to terminate kafka connection...!");
        process.exit(0);
    });
}
module.exports = exports = new ConnectionProvider;
```

Topic publish Method:

```
const kafkaClient = require('./../core/kafkaConnection');

    const publishToKafka = function(dataPayload, callback) {
        logger.debug('Publishing to topic ', topicName, ' with data: ', dataPayload);
        let producer = kafkaClient.getConnection();

        producer.on('ready', function() {
            let payloads = dataPayload;
            producer.send(payloads, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.error(
                        'Error in publishing message to messaging pipeline ', err
                    );
                    callback(err, null);
                    return;
                }

                logger.debug('Published message to messaging pipeline topic ', topicName, ' with result: ', data);

                callback(null, data);
                return;
            });
        });

        producer.on('error', function(err) {
            logger.error(
                'Error in publishing message to messaging pipeline ', err
            );
            producer.close();
        });

    };
```

DataPayload is :
let dataPayload=[{topic:someTopic,message:someMessage}]

I need to call PublishToKafka method multiple times but want to create only one kafka client and producer instance.
But producer is not publishing Topics because producer.on('ready',function(){}) not getting triggered while using the same object of client and producer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by closing the kafka producer and client instance after every call,because i need to publish to kafka producer multiple times but by default kafka zookeeper only allow 60 max connection (we can increase the value of connection if we want). So that's why created singleton class for single kafka instance.

But After creating single instance of kafka ,its producer.on('ready') event will not triggered because second time when we used the same object of kafka producer that is  already is in ready state . so we need new producer instance for  publishing every time.

```
const publishToKafka = function(topicName, dataPayload, callback) {
    logger.debug('Publishing to topic ', topicName, ' with data: ', dataPayload);
    let client = new kafka.Client(kakfaConfig.ZOOKPER_HOST);
    let producer = new kafka.Producer(client);


    producer.on('ready', function() {
        let payloads = dataPayload;
        producer.send(payloads, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                logger.error(
                    'Error in publishing message to messaging pipeline ', err
                );
                callback(err, null);
                return;
            }

            logger.debug('Published message to messaging pipeline topic ', topicName, ' with result: ', data);
            producer.close();
            client.close();
            callback(null, data);

            return;
        });
    });

    producer.on('error', function(err) {
        logger.error(
            'Error in publishing message to messaging pipeline ', err
        );
        producer.close();
    });

};
```

no need to create singleton class for single object.